# Facebook messenger 3rd party capability

Tags: facebook

trying to find out following with regard to Facebook Messenger 3rd party app API:

Are you able to send HTML content inside the message?

Is there a payments APi yet?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send HTML content and we don't have a Payments API yet.